# Invalid object name 'PetDatabase.Sales'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

Im trying to run the following to import a large volume of sales data in a text file into a database. When i run the following i get the error: "Invalid object name 'PetDatabase.Sales'

```
BULK INSERT PetDatabase.Sales
FROM 'C:\Temp\P1.txt'
WITH 
(
  FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\PetSales.Fmt'
);
```

Can anyone see whats causing my problem? I do have the tables within a folder; however, when i tried PetsDatabase.Tables.Sales it made no difference.

Comment: Um, isn't `BULK INSERT` an SQL Server command?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yup. `BULK INSERT` is a T-SQL statement, and the most equivalent in MySQL is `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore this answer. It was written when the question was tagged with `mysql`. Leaving the answer here to keep the comments.

--

Try using `LOAD DATA INFILE` instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I now get the error: incorrect syntax near 'INFILE'. I assumed it was because i was missing a semi-colon on each line however ive put them both in and its made no difference. Please advise.

Comment: @user1091114 The syntax for `LOAD DATA INFILE` is not the same as the syntax for `BULK INSERT`. Please post your new SQL in your question, and let us know what version of MySQL you're running (you can issue the `STATUS;` command to get the server version).

Comment: Im using SQL within Visual Studio 2010, SQL 2008

Comment: So you are using MSSQL. Your post is tagged as MySQL. I'm going to retag your post so you can get answers from the right people (MSSQL experts).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure PetDatabase.Sales exists in your text file.
2. Swap for whichever row and field terminator delimiters you're using. Here I'm using delimiters from a comma separated file

   BULK INSERT PetDatabase
   FROM 'c:\temp\p1.txt'
   WITH
   (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   )
   GO
   --Check the content of the table.
   SELECT *
   FROM PetDatabase
   GO
   --Drop the table to clean up database.
   SELECT *
   FROM PetDatabase
   GO

Also, make sure the following doesn't apply to you:

If a SQL Server user is logged in using Windows Authentication, the user can read only the files accessible to the user account, independent of the security profile of the SQL Server process.

When executing the BULK INSERT statement by using sqlcmd or osql, from one computer, inserting data into SQL Server on a second computer, and specifying a data_file on third computer by using a UNC path, you may receive a 4861 error.

To resolve this error, use SQL Server Authentication and specify a SQL Server login that uses the security profile of the SQL Server process account, or configure Windows to enable security account delegation.

Comment: Where should it exist in my text file? I have followed the information on this site and doesnt reference any tables in the text file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx

Comment: your first row in the flat file should contain the field names, if you have the field names at all. fieldname1, fieldname2, filedname3

Comment: Please could you refer me to an example since its not what ive been following on the MDSN site and a bit confused :@

Comment: I see you have a sales column. In case your sales are formatted with commas, you also may want to add a text qualifier in your csv file

Comment: I have a format file called PetSales, i have a text file (P1) with all my data in, and one of my tables in the database is called 'Sales'

Comment: INSERT INTO PetDatabase
    SELECT sales
      FROM  (BULK INSERT PetDatabase 
   FROM 'C:\Temp\P1.txt' 
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\PetSales.Fmt');) as t1 ;
GO  <-- I think thats correct

Comment: I get the following error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BULK'. Incorrect syntax near ')'"

Answer (score 0):

Is PetDatabase is schema name or database name?
If it is database name, then include schema name also like this if your schema name is dbo.

```
PetDatabase.dbo.Sales
```